# How to consume OData service on SAP BW from an external system?

Tags: odata, saprfc, sap-gateway, sap-bw

I'm trying to call an OData service that executes a query on SAP BW (SAP NetWeaver 7.5 with HANA database) from a system external to SAP.
I followed the steps in this guide: https://help.sap.com/docs/SUPPORT_CONTENT/bwplaolap/3361385310.html
but I can't call the service.
I get the following error:

> No permission to access service '<name of the service>'

Could you help me identify which permissions are missing?

I was also wondering if a connection with the external system should be defined for consuming the OData service from a non-SAP system (for example via RFC and creation of an alias, as if I were calling the service from a FIORI app).